# Why is there a huge air-conditioner in the foyer in MIB?

Tags: men-in-black

Anyone who has seen *Men in Black* will recall that the foyer of the *MIB* building is a large room with what looks like an air-conditioner and a man sitting on a chair.  I was wondering whether there is any significance to this and, if so, what that significance would be?  It's been bugging me (sorry - bad joke) for quite some time.

[image]

Comment: +1 just for the awful "bugging me" pun

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The MIB Building is concealed below the [Brooklyn Battery Tunnel (Now Hugh L. Carey Tunnel) Ventilation building](https://foursquare.com/v/brooklyn-battery-tunnel-ventilation-building/4e343e7618a8efdb17627632)

The implication seems to be the "front" of the building (pun intended) is the ventilation bit, complete with a giant fan and vent, providing air not only to the building and tunnel but also to the **vast** airport-sized complex concealed below it.

Note that the fan allows the guard to remain at his post when the building is "flushed" in the second film, despite what should be a **massive** change in air pressure so the fan clearly serves a secondary purpose.

[image]

> [Originally,](http://www.themeparkinsider.com/flume/200904/1173/) the building was going to look just like the ventilation
>   building of the Brooklyn Battery Tunnel, and guests would walk past
>   the giant fan & vent before taking the elevator down to HQ -- just
>   like in the film.

Comment: This answer is just another kind of fan service ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - I appreciate that you want to vent your opinion but that comment was little more than hot air.

Comment: Another wind pun.

Comment: @Richard: No need to blow away his awesome pun.

Comment: Now, now - this flurry of puns is quickly becoming a tempest of silliness.

Comment: @omegacron - agreed. He needs to chill out

Comment: @Richard - A/C what you did there!

Comment: You guys are always blowing hot and cold